# python : template var without space

Tags: python, templates

in python, I try use templates

```
 from string import Template
 s = Template("hello $world")
 print s.substitute(world="Stackoverflow")
```

ok, but, In the template I need concatenate a string without space, example

```
 s = Template("a small number : $number e6")
 print s.substitute(number=5)
```

I need `a small number : 5e6` as output, without white space between 5 and e6.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use curly braces around the pattern:

```
Template("a small number : ${number}e6")
```

Result:

```
>>> Template("a small number : ${number}e6").substitute(number=5)
'a small number : 5e6'
```